# MySQL - Setting value in only one of two columns which share a common value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `contacts` table with an auto-incrementing primary key `id` and a self referential one-to-one relationship on the `partner_id` column.

I'm importing many contacts from CSVs from various sources, some of which are very poorly presented so I'm having to apply some smarts to work out who is whos partner, if they have one at all.

I've gotten to the stage where after the import, I have the rows in the contacts table, and any pairs I've determined to be partners share a value unique to that pair in the `import_group` column.

I'm now stuck on writing a query to do the following:

Where two rows share the same value in `import_group`, set the `partner_id` of the first of the two rows to the `id` of the second of the two rows, but do not set `partner_id` of the second row to the `id` of the first. This structure is a requirement due to the design of the application referencing this database.

This is going to be run on a table containing a max of ~4,000,000 rows, less than once a month during manual imports run by a system administrator, so efficiency is not a particular target of this query.

How can I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a self-join, if you sort by id you can use a WHERE clause that ensures you only get one of each pair. For example,

```
UPDATE contacts as c1
    JOIN contacts as c2
        ON c2.import_group = c1.import_group
    SET c1.partner_id = c2.id
WHERE c1.id < c2.id;
```

I can't access sql fiddle, so here is how I tested it:

```
create table contacts (id int, import_group int, partner_id int);
insert into contacts values (1, NULL, NULL), (2, 100, NULL), (3, 100, NULL), (4, NULL, NULL), (5, 101, NULL), (6, NULL, NULL), (7, 101, NULL);

select * from contacts;
+------+--------------+---------+
| id   | import_group | partner |
+------+--------------+---------+
|    1 |         NULL |    NULL |
|    2 |          100 |       3 |
|    3 |          100 |    NULL |
|    4 |         NULL |    NULL |
|    5 |          101 |       7 |
|    6 |         NULL |    NULL |
|    7 |          101 |    NULL |
+------+--------------+---------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Seems so easy when someone else does it... thanks for that =]

Answer (score 0):

You can identify all the partners with a self-join.  Then you only want to set the one that has "lower" `contact.id`.

The following update does a self join on `contact` to find the partner.  It then has an inequality so it keeps the first of the rows for the `set`:

```
update contacts c join
       contacts cpart
       on c.import_group = cpart.import_group and
          c.id < cpart.id
    set c.partner_id = cpart.id;
```

Note:  this assumes that all partnerships are binary.  If you have multi-way partnerships, a bit more information is needed on what the data should look like.